# List of authors in Wordpress with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a special page to show up all the authors and contributors for a website. I'm using ACF fields for the users and these fields are not showing up.

According to ACF support, I should use this:

```
    <?php

$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$author_badge = get_field('author_badge', 'user_'. $author_id );

?>
<img src="<?php echo $author_badge['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $author_badge['alt']; ?>" />
```

My code at the moment is:

```
<?php
      foreach($users as $user)
      {
         ?>
         <div class="s-12 l-4 margin-bottom">

               <div class="theBox">
               <figure class="effect-zoe">

            <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta( $userID ); ?></p>

                  <?php

$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$author_badge = get_field('author_badge', 'user_'. $author_id );

?>
<img src="<?php echo $author_badge['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $author_badge['alt']; ?>" />


                  <figcaption>
                     <p><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>">view profile</a></p>
                  </figcaption>      

               </figure>
               <h3><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h3> 
            </div>

            </div>
         <?php
      }
   ?>
```

Only the ACF field is not working. Any tip on how to fix it?

One more thing: If I use this: `<?php the_field('field_name', 'user_1'); ?>` works! But this is not what I want, once I need to show a list of users with their respective ACF fields filled.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it.

Just use the concatenation with $user->ID under this syntax. So the result is:

```
<?php the_field('profile_picture', 'user_'.$user->ID);  ?>
```